# Example of surjective sheaf morphisms which are not surjective on sections

Tags: differential-geometry, sheaf-theory, spin-geometry

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\varphi \colon \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}$ be a sheaf morphism on $X$.I know that surjectiveness of $\varphi$ means surjective stalk homomorphisms $\varphi_x \colon \mathcal{f}_x \to \mathcal{G}_x $ for any $x \in X$, but the section maps $\varphi_{U} \colon \mathcal{F}(U) \to \mathcal{G}(U)$ need not be surjective.
I already know some example of surjective $\varphi \colon \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}$ but not surjective $\varphi_{U} \colon \mathcal{F}(U) \to \mathcal{G}(U) $.

Now I’m studying a definition of spin structure on differentiable manifold.It appears surjective sheaf morphisms $\exp \colon \underline{\mathbb{R}} \to \underline{U(1)}$and $Ad \colon \underline{Spin(n)} \to \underline{SO(n)} $.Where, they are sheaf morphisms between smooth functions and 1-dimensional unitary groups, n-dimensional spin groups and special orthonormal groups on differential manifold.

**Question.** Are these sheaf morphisms always induce surjections on sections?I think it’s not true.
If it’s not true, please construct some example.

Comment: For $exp$, consider the case of the manifold $S^1$, and study the pre-image of the section $s(x)=x$ of the bundle $U(1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I can get a good example for $\exp$.